# iPhone: detecting if a UIAlert/UIActionSheet are open

Tags: iphone, uialertview, uiactionsheet

In my iOS application, I have a timer firing up, and when it fires, I need to be able to detect whether there's an Alert (UIAlertView) or an Action Sheet (UIActionSheet) open.

One way would be to modify the code presenting the alerts/actionsheets - but unfortunately this is not an option in my case.

So, the question is - is there a way of knowing/detecting whether an alert or action sheet have been opened?

Is there any notifications sent upon opening, or any traversal of the view hierarchy to detect it?

Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

They do send an alert when they open, but only to their `delegate` -- Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1861369/check-if-a-uialertview-is-visible) for a nice approach to that problem. Techzen recommends setting a boolean flag to `YES` when you open up the alert, and setting it back to `NO` when you dismiss the alert.

EDIT:

Since you don't have access at all to the code, why not try this clunky piece of code:

```
-(BOOL) doesAlertViewExist {
  for (UIWindow* window in [UIApplication sharedApplication].windows) {
    NSArray* subviews = window.subviews;
    if ([subviews count] > 0) {

      BOOL alert = [[subviews objectAtIndex:0] isKindOfClass:[UIAlertView class]];
      BOOL action = [[subviews objectAtIndex:0] isKindOfClass:[UIActionSheet class]];

      if (alert || action)
        return YES;
     }
  }
  return NO;
}
```

Comment: THANKS! I had to apply two changes to the proposal: (1) subviews in an NSArray* and not UIView*. (2) Seems like the UIActionSheet is not the first [0] subview, but the second [1]. So I iterated the view hierarchy... Code is posted as answer...

Comment: I used TechZen's other suggestion of retaining a reference. I found this worked very elegantly.

Answer (score 12):

```
- (BOOL) doesAlertViewExist {
    for (UIWindow* window in [UIApplication sharedApplication].windows) {
        for (UIView* view in window.subviews) {
            BOOL alert = [view isKindOfClass:[UIAlertView class]];
            BOOL action = [view isKindOfClass:[UIActionSheet class]];
            if (alert || action)
                return YES;
        }
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: hello i am also facing same problem i tried with the above code however when i try to print the array of "window.subviews" , not getting any object of uiactionsheet .Before this i kept open one actionsheet .what can be the problem please give some solution on this

Comment: I've only used this code on an iPhone - can it be you're using it on an iPad?

Comment: Not Working at all on ipad. :(

Answer (score 2):

You can also check for the view's window property:

```
if(actionSheet.window)
    isBeingPresented = YES;
```

Answer (score 2):

Detecting alerts seems relatively easy, but action sheets had me stumped. In iOS 6.1 I had to go one step further

```
BOOL IsActionOpen(UIView* aView) {
BOOL    actionOpen = NO;
if (aView) {
    if ([aView isKindOfClass:[UIActionSheet class]]) {
        actionOpen = YES;
    }
    else if (aView.subviews.count > 0) {
        for (UIView* aSubview in aView.subviews) {
            if ( IsActionOpen( aSubview)) {
                actionOpen = YES;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
return actionOpen;
```

}

```
- (BOOL) isAnActionSheetOpen {
BOOL    actionOpen = NO;
for (UIWindow* w in [UIApplication sharedApplication].windows) {
    actionOpen =  IsActionOpen(w);
    if (actionOpen)
        break;
}
return actionOpen;
```

}

Comment: In iOS 7 this code works for action sheets, but it no longer works for alert views. Seems like the best solution for alert views is to keep track of them... http://stackoverflow.com/q/18702565/268153

Answer (score 1):

thanx for the help, but since iOS 6, the code piece doesn't work anymore.
However, I fixed the issue with this code. Hope this helps

```
for (UIWindow* window in [UIApplication sharedApplication].windows) {
    NSArray* subviews = window.subviews;
    if ([subviews count] > 1) {
        BOOL alert = [[subviews objectAtIndex:1] isKindOfClass:[UIAlertView class]];
        BOOL action = [[subviews objectAtIndex:1] isKindOfClass:[UIActionSheet class]];

        if (alert || action)
            return YES;
    }
}
return NO;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
-(BOOL)GetKeyWindow {    
        UIViewController *presentedViewController = myAppDelegate.window.rootViewController.presentedViewController;

        if (presentedViewController) {

            if ([presentedViewController isKindOfClass:[UIActivityViewController class]] || [presentedViewController isKindOfClass:[UIAlertController class]]) {        

                return YES;
            }else{
                return NO;
                NSLog(@"not present");
            }   
        }
        else{
            return NO;
        } 
}
```