# alert view present on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, uialertview

I want to check whether the UIALertView is present on the screen or not, though I have done it by using the following method:

```
-(BOOL) isAlertShowing
{

    for (UIWindow* window in [UIApplication sharedApplication].windows) {
        NSArray* subviews = window.subviews;
        if ([subviews count] > 0)
            if ([[subviews objectAtIndex:0] isKindOfClass:[UIAlertView class]])
                return YES;
    }
    return NO;      
}
```

but I came to know that it is undocumented one. So, please tell me authenticate way of doing it.

Comment: do one thing when you present the alert view by [alert show] method so after dat maintain a BOOL variable YES.

Comment: I don't see any private API in your method. It won't win a beauty contest, but it ain't wrong either.

Comment: Actually, I want the alert to be shown when its not done by my device, itself. For example, in case of location services, if device doesn't show alert, then I want to show my custom alert.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you even need this? Don't you know when you've presented an alert and when it's been dismissed by hitting one of the buttons?

Comment: hey Brad, as the system is responsible for alerting the user (in case of GPS alert), we don't know how to catch the button method

Answer (score 0):

In an app I submitted (and is approved), I have used a similar approach (see [iPhone: detecting if a UIAlert/UIActionSheet are open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4363317/iphone-detecting-if-a-uialert-uiactionsheet-are-open))...

I don't see why you think it's not a valid method - I'd try it.