# Dismiss UIActionSheet opened from UIWebView

Tags: iphone, ios, webview, uiactionsheet, dismiss

I use a web view with auto detecting phone numbers. If I tap on a phone link in the web view on my iPad the default action sheet is opened with add to contacts, copy and cancel buttons. Since I have no reference to the menu how can I dismiss this sheet when the app enters background state?

Best Regards
Carsten

Comment: means you want to disable that link ?

Comment: Nope I want to execute the default action (in this case the action sheet is opened automatically) and dismiss the action sheet if the app is suspended. I am just curious if this is possible and how.

Answer (score 0):

You could try looking at the [UIWebView Development Document](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIWebViewDelegate/webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:), more importantly `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:`
and you can look at the UIActionSheet delegate function referenced from this stackoverflow link [iPhone Detecting if a UIAlert UIActionSheet are open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4363317/iphone-detecting-if-a-uialert-uiactionsheet-are-open) and in the delegate method, you can see that

```
if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIActionSheet class]] && [[view buttonTitleAtIndex:0] isEqualToString:@"Call"]) {
    // Dismiss actionSheet
}
```

Also look at `dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:animated:` in [UIActionSheet Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html) which may do what you are looking for in terms of closing.