# How to know if there is a UIActionSheet showing in view Hierarchy?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactionsheet

How to know if there is a `UIActionSheet` showing in `View Hierarchy`?
Also I want to get a reference to that `UIActionSheet`, any good idea?

Comment: use tags for actionsheets and implement the delegates.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4363317/iphone-detecting-if-a-uialert-uiactionsheet-are-open, take a look at the second answer

Comment: @RoxDorentus I don't think its a total duplicate, but it do solved my problem, thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Notice that on iOS6, you need a recursive search to finde the UIActionSheet, it is not a direct subview of UIWindow now.

```
static UIView *actionSheet = nil;
-(void)findActionSheetInSubviewsOfView:(id)view
{
    if (actionSheet) {
        return;
    }
    if ([[view valueForKey:@"subviews"] count] != 0) {
        for (id subview in [view valueForKey:@"subviews"]) {
            if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UIActionSheet class]]) {
                actionSheet = subview;
            }
            else
                [self findActionSheetInSubviewsOfView:subview];
        }
    }
}

-(UIActionSheet*) actionSheetShowing {
    actionSheet = nil;
    for (UIWindow* window in [UIApplication sharedApplication].windows) {
        [self findActionSheetInSubviewsOfView:window];
    }

    if (actionSheet) {
        return (UIActionSheet*)actionSheet;
    }
    return nil;
}
```